# Cant find configure file in tar.gz

Tags: tar, configure

I was trying to install Kompozer. I've downloaded the `tar.gz` file and tried to install it. After unzipping I can't find the `configure` file in it. How could I install it?

Comment: Did you extract the files from the `.tar.gz` or just decompress it? Look among the files that came out of the `.tar.gz` for `README*` or any other file whose name is all upper case

Comment: KDE-apps usually use cmake, in this case you don't do `./configure && make && make install`. Instead: `mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make install`

Answer (score 0):

To build from source code then visit the [download page](http://www.kompozer.net/download.php) and you can find the instructions linked from [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwjI2uS-3OvGAhWBlRQKHWgKDG0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fkompozer.sourceforge.net%2Fdev%2F&ei=ovetVciBFoGrUuiUsOgG&usg=AFQjCNE3ZmLbIKjKbc0nugq8uKsqyBXagQ&sig2=NdPNfcdo2OdFeYbQ04kNSQ&bvm=bv.98197061,d.d24). It's too long to list here and too hard to implement, instead you can install it this way:

If you use Ubuntu 12.04 you can use the PPA:

```
sudo apt-get install kompozer
```

Else if you Ubuntu version is greater(>14.04) then you can install it[<sub>source</sub>](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallKompozer) this way:

First, install dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk2.0-0  libidl0 libnspr4 libnss3 libpango1.0-0 libpng12-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libxft2 libxinerama1 libxrender1 libxt6 zlib1g
```

Then, get the two packages, and install them in the correct order.

For 32bit systems:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer-data_0.8%7Eb3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer_0.8%7Eb3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i kompozer-data_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_i386.deb
```

if you have error then run:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

for 64bit systems:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer-data_0.8%7Eb3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer_0.8%7Eb3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i kompozer-data_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

if you have error then run:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```